# How to check integer overflow in Java?

Tags: java, casting, int, double, integer-overflow

int a = 200000;

double b = (double) (a*a);

I would like to be able to calculate if (a*a) (integers) is already too large (stackOverflow) to hold in the variable; in this case I know that multiplying (a*a) leads to an int that will not fit -> the number will be wrong;

What I do not understand is how I can calculate this off the top of my head. How can I see if a value will not fit in an int variable??

Is there a way to do this without using methods, by just using the plain code and common sense? ;-)

Best regards,

Wouter

Comment: what do you mean by too large or too big

Comment: In Java *plain code* should be inside a method.

Comment: You can convert to long, do the calculation, and determine if the value is larger than Integer.MaxValue

Comment: Do you mean integer overflow instead of stack overflow?

Comment: Too large for what? If `a` is a `long`, `float`, or `double`, your calculations will not overflow. Perhaps if your code has said `int a = 200000;`, it wouldn't be ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Two possible solutions.

Catch exception thrown after a call to the `Math.…Exact` methods: [`Math.multiplyExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(int,int)), [`Math.addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(int,int)), [`Math.decrementExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#decrementExact(int)), and so on.

```
 int a = 200000;

  try {
      int result = Math.multiplyExact(x, y);

  } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
      //if you get here, it is too big
  }
```

Or, check against the constants for [minimum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and [maximum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) possible integer values.

```
 long test = (long)a*(long)a;
 if (test > Integer.MAX_VALUE || test < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    // Overflow!
```

Comment: You only need to cast explicitly one operand to long, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the constant MAX_VALUE from the Integer wrapper class and cast to long instead (you will get a compile error if you cast to double but exceed it's range)

```
    int a = 200000;
    long b = (long) a * (long) a;
    if (b > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // do something
    }
```

MAX_VALUE corresponds to the highest value an integer can be, (2^31)-1

Comment: I think this won't work, as the conversion to long is done after the int multiplication.